# Fluid Statics Problem

Tags: fluid-mechanics, statics, water-resources, fluid

I have been attempting this question for a while now. Could anyone give me a hand?

The question and the work I have done so far is below. My final "answer" is 
P (force required to keep the gate closed) = 109,100.1526w + 346.84 (where w is the width of the gate). Since i cannot rearrange my answer in the form "P/w", I am assuming I have made a mistake somewhere, but I cannot identify my mistake.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure you can describe this in terms of $P/w$. It'll mean you'll have $346.84/w$ as part of the answer, but that's unavoidable, given that you were given the total mass of the gate but not its width. Also, why do you assume $P$ is applied in the middle of the gate?

Comment: be sure to read the original question text carefully in case they actually specified weight per width.

Comment: @Wasabi I have no reason in particular for putting P at the center. But now that you mention, it seems it would make more sense to put it at the top, right?

Comment: @agentp Unfortunately not. All that is given is that's in the first image. I only have weight, not weight/width. With what I'm given, is there a way to find an answer (Force/width) which doesn't include the "w" (width) on the RHS?

Comment: @Tin263: Well, with the force at the top you maximize the moment/force ratio, reducing the necessary force by 2. And no, you can't avoid having $w$ on the RHS, if you're given the mass but not the dimensions. If you were given the mass per width, then the second part of the equation would begin with $50w$, which would allow you to find a "clean" $P/w$. But since you don't have that, there's nothing you can do. To be super pedantic, you calculate the mass per width as $50/w$ and then find the total mass as $50/w\cdot w$, and the $w$'s cancel out.